# LLVM IR: How to call a function in another .ll file

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api, llvm-3.0

I am writing LLVM IR code, can I call a function in another .ll file?

For example:
In a.ll file, there is a function foo();
Can I use this function in b.ll, like just call foo? If so, how can I include a.ll

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to add declaration of function foo in the ll file in which you are calling it, then as usual convert link ll files to generate executable

```
 llvm-link a.ll b.ll -o a.out
```

example 
a.ll

```
declare i32 @foo(i32)

define i32 @main() {
    start:
    %0 = call i32 @foo(i32 0)
    ret i32 %0
}
```

b.ll

```
define i32 @foo(i32) {
    start:
    ret i32 %0
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But if I have a function foo2() in a.ll which use foo() in b.ll, can I use C++ API parseIRFile to extract the foo2() function, and make it run in c++ code? If so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above procedure but the `a.out` file produced is not an executable. It initially gives a `Permission denied` error and after adding the appropriate permissions says:

`-bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file`

Taking the same two llvm files i.e `a.ll` and `b.ll` what works for me is:

```
llvm-link-8 -S a.ll b.ll > hello.ll
llc-8 -filetype=obj hello.ll
clang hello.o
```

The following 3 commands creates an executable which executes fine. The first command creates an LLVM bitcode file called `hello.ll` which links `a.ll` and `b.ll`. After that it is simply a process of creating an executable binary from an llvm bitcode file. which the next 2 steps do. (Note that I am using LLVM 8)